# Icon missing in installed app?

Tags: java, android

So I have been working on a basic android application but when ever I load it on the emulator it used to work but now the icon is simply not there its not installed the application. I have tried all version of the Android this did not fix the issue. I tried using my own Android device it worked for 3 days and then it simply stopped working as well. So each time I compile the code it works but the application is not installed on any device what so ever. So far I tried factor reset phone, Reinstall Android Studio and Different Emulator version nothing worked.

Any ideas or solutions?

**Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.edgaraxelsson.myapplication.STARTINGPOINT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.edgaraxelsson.myapplication.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Text"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>
```

**Compiler output**:

```
Testing started at 10:19 ...
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-sm_g900f-cd9e70da
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Edgar Axelsson\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.edgaraxelsson.myapplication
No apk changes detected. Skipping file upload.
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Edgar Axelsson\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-test-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.edgaraxelsson.myapplication.test
No apk changes detected. Skipping file upload.
Running tests
Test running startedFinish
```

Comment: What does it say when it tries to launch? Does it show the dialogue  to select a device? Does it say it's both Online and Compatible?

Comment: The problem should be in your AndroidManifest.xml file. Don't you want to show it?

Comment: Online and Compatible

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is you changed something in the manifest between the app working and its current state. As a disclaimer, I'm not an Android specialist but something jumps out at me right away in terms of my experience - you don't have a launcher category defined for any of your activities.

From the [Android Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#CategoryTest) (emphasis mine):

> Intents are matched against intent filters not only to discover a
>   target component to activate, but also to discover something about the
>   set of components on the device. *For example, the Home app populates
>   the app launcher by finding all the activities with intent filters
>   that specify the **ACTION_MAIN** action and **CATEGORY_LAUNCHER**
>   category*.

This is what you're missing in your manifest; a `LAUNCHER`.

In every app I've made there was one; I just altered the manifest of the current app I'm working on to reflect a `DEFAULT` for my launcher activity, and it broke.

So, in your manifest you have...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    ...
```

I think you should "match" your intents and do...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    ...
```

instead.